# How to find $\ker T$ from matrix representation over polynomial finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, linear-transformations, finite-fields

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of 5 elements (essentially $\mathbb Z_5$).
>
> $T:\mathbb F_3[x] \to \mathbb F_3[x]$ is a linear map defined by the representation matrix:
>   $$
> [T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3\\
> 1&0&4\\
> 0&1&2
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   with the basis $B=(1, 1+x,1+x+x^2)$. Find $\text{ker}T$.
>
> $\mathbb F_3[x]$ is a space of polynomials of form $ax^2+bx+c$ over $\mathbb F$.

We know that if a vector $v\in \text{ker}T$ then $[v]_B$ is in the nullity space of $[T]_B$.

If we row reduce $[T]_B$ and solve the system for $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
1&0&4\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\\Row_2\to Row_2-Row_1 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&3&1\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\\
Row_3\to Row_3-3^{-1}Row_2\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\\
Row_2\to 3^{-1}Row_2\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

So: 
$$
x_2=-2x_3=3x_3 \quad(??)\\
x_1=-2x_2-3x_3=3\cdot 3x_3+2x_3=4x_3+2x_3=x_3 \quad(??)
$$

and the general solution is: $(x_3,3x_3,x_3)$ from which follows that $\text{ker}T=span\{1,3,1\}$.

I'm not sure whether my calculations are correct especially when calculating the general solution.

Also I'm not sure how/whether to take into consideration that a vector belonging to $\text{ker}T$ is actually a polynomial.

Comment: What do you denote $\mathbb F_3[x]$?

Comment: @Bernard I gave the definition in the post. "$\mathbb F_3[x]$ is a space of polynomials of form $ax^2+bx+c$ over $\mathbb F$"

Comment: Why the 3? I think the usual notation would use `2`.

Comment: @Bernard in our course they define it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row reduction is
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
1&0&4\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&3&1\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_2\gets R_2-R_1
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&1&2\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_2\gets 3^{-1}R_2
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3-R_2
\\&\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&4\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
&& R_1\gets R_1-R_2
\end{align}
This means that the third variable is free, so a basis of the null space of the matrix is given by the single vector
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
This vector gives the coordinates of the generator of the kernel with respect to $B$. Therefore a basis for the kernel is given by the single polynomial
$$
1\cdot 1+3\cdot(1+x)+1\cdot(1+x+x^2)=4x+x^2
$$

Comment: Why $1\cdot 1+3\cdot(1+x)+1\cdot(1+x+x^2)=4+4x+x^2$ and not $1\cdot 1+3\cdot(1+x)+1\cdot(1+x+x^2)=1+3+1+4x+x^2=5+4x+x^2=0+4x+x^2$?

Comment: If for example the linear map was $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ and I would've been given a standard basis $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ how would I convert the $[v]_B$ vector to its original base? By $B\cdot [v]_B$?

Comment: @Yos Sorry for the mistake. The final computation would be exactly the same, using the basis vectors.

Comment: Do I have to convert the vector $[v]_B$ I found to the polynomial form?

Comment: @Yos Sorry, I don't understand. If the space is $\mathh{R}^3$, there's no polynomial involved.

Comment: Sorry I meant if we return to the original problem in the post when $T:\mathbb F_3[x]\to \mathbb F_3[x]$

Answer (score 2):

Even without reducing, you could write down this:
$\ker(T)=\{v\in V | T(v)=0\}$

So, from your matrix you see that:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
1&0&4\\
0&1&2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \\x_3 \end{pmatrix}=0 \iff \begin{equation} \begin{cases}x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0\\x_1+4x_3=0\\x_2+2x_3=0 \end{cases}\end{equation}$$

From which you obtain that: \begin{equation} \begin{cases}z=\alpha\\y=-2\alpha\\x=-4\alpha \end{cases}\end{equation} So the solution is $\text{Span}(-4,-2,1)=\text{Span}(1,3,1)$

Comment: I noticed you're not converting the vector $[v]_B=(1,3,1)$ that we found into polynomial form. Don't we need to?

Comment: $(1,3,1) = [v]_B$ are the coordinates of the vector in your basis. So, if you want the explicit form of the polynomial generating your Kernel you can write it down. In fact, if you call $C=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ the basis of $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ the vector generating the Kernel is $1v_1+3v_2+1v_3$. In fact the map sending each vector $v\in \mathbb{F}_3[x] \rightarrow [v]_B$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Would the $dimKerT=2$ when in polynomial form?

Comment: No! As it is an isomorphism, the dimension of the Kernel it's always $1$.

Comment: And I know it's an isomorphism because $T: Hom(V,W) \to M$ where $M$ is a representation matrix is always an isomorphism?

Comment: The map sending each vector in his coordinates is an isomorphism.

Comment: If our linear map is an isomorphism than $kerT$ only contains the zero vector which would make $dimKerT=0$ no?

Comment: Remember that the map $T$ you are considering in comments is different from the one in your post. By the way, yes, if a map is an isomorphism the dimension of the Kernel is $0$. In fact, how do you say what is the dimension of $Hom(V,W)$? Simply by constructing an isomorphism from $Hom(V,W) \rightarrow M(n,m,\mathbb{K})$!

Comment: But which map did you mean when you said that "As it is an isomorphism the dimension of the kernel is always one"?

Comment: The maps sending you each vector into his coordinates. (By the way, if you want to continue discussing let's continue in chat, we don't wanna extend the discussion in comments :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60984/discussion-between-yos-and-alberto-andrenucci).