# How to calculate $T(ax^2+bx+c)$ according to basis $B=(1,1+x,1+x+x^2)$ if $T:\mathbb F_3[x]\to \mathbb F_3[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field of 5 elements (essentially $\mathbb Z_5$).
>
> $T:\mathbb F_3[x] \to \mathbb F_3[x]$ is a linear map defined by the representation matrix:
>   $$
> [T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3\\
> 1&0&4\\
> 0&1&2
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   with the basis $B=(1, 1+x,1+x+x^2)$. 
>   $\mathbb F_3[x]$ is a space of polynomials of form $ax^2+bx+c$ over $\mathbb F$.
>
> Calculate $T(ax^2+bx+c)$.

This question is builds on this question [How to find $\ker T$ from matrix representation over polynomial finite field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332575/how-to-find-ker-t-from-matrix-representation-over-polynomial-finite-field).

As a first step I'd need to convert the basis $B$ into coordinate vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ according to the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.

I don't really know what the coordinate representations should be for $B$. Should it be $1 \to (1,0,0), 1+x \to (0,1,0), 1+x+x^2 \to (0,0,1)$?

Now I also need to convert the vector $v=ax^2+bx+c$ into coordinate form according to the standard basis $E$. Should it be $[v]_E=(a,b,c)$?

Now I need to find the solution to the system $E_3x=[v]_E \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$

As the last step I'd need to do the required calculation itself:
$$
T(a,b,c)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\1&0&4\\0&1&2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}
$$

My main question is how to convert the given basis $B$ and polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ into vector coordinates according to standard basis $E$ and whether I missed any steps in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,b,c)$ are the coordinates of $f=ax^2+bx+c$ w.r.t. the basis $(1,x,x^2)$

since $T$ is given in terms of a different basis $B$, to apply it to $f$ we need to express $f$ in terms of the basis $B$.

suppose the new $T$-compatible coordinates of $f$ are $(a',b',c')$ then
$$
a'1+b'(1+x) +c'(1+x+x^2) = a+bx +cx^2
$$
comparing coefficients of $x^2$ gives $c'=c$.

for coefficients of $x$ we have $b'+c' =b$ so $b' = b-c'= b-c$

for the constant term $a'+b'+c' = a$ giving $a'= a-b'-c' = a-(b-c)-c = a-b$

the new coordinates of $f$ are thus $(a-b,b-c,c)$. now
$$
Tf =\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\1&0&4\\0&1&2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}a-b\\b-c\\c\end{pmatrix}
$$
the answer will be a vector expressed in terms of the basis $B$, so your final step is to convert this back to a polynomial in the familiar basis $(1,x,x^2)$ which should be straightforward.

Comment: Why do we need to convert the result vector into $(1,x,x^2$? Isn't it enough to get the result according to $B$ because this is our original basis anyway?

Comment: the conversion is a fairly simple rewriting, but if the output from $Tf$ as above is, say, $(p,q,r)$ then this is the polynomial $p.1+q(1+x)+r(1+x+x^2)$, which we expect to be written as $(p+q+r) +(q+r)x+ rx^2$

Comment: So it's just rearranging the terms essentially? I just don't understand why we need to do this rearrangement

Comment: well you can (using ordinary algebra) write the same polynomial function in many different ways. but when we view it as an element of a $3-$dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ then we must write it as a sum of three elements, each consisting of a real coefficient and a basis element. if you wish to leave it in the "unsimplified" form, then you still have the same polynomial function.